# Onelogin SAML Assertion Verify Factor with authentication denied

Tags: api, saml, onelogin, multi-factor-authentication

I have some code that uses the Generate SAML Assertion API with users that have MFA (OneLogin Protect) enabled.

Send the Generate SAML Assertion Request, receive a response that Factor Verification is required.

Send the Factor Verify request with app_id, device_id, state_token and do_not_notify=false. This all works well. I receive the notification on my phone.

The code keeps sending the Factor Verify request every 15 seconds (with do_not_notify=true) and waits for the response to contain a data attribute (which is the SAML assertion).

When clicking "Accept" on the phone, the next response will contain the data and everything is well.

But clicking "Deny" on my phone does nothing. All API call contain the message "Authentication pending on OL Protect" (same if not clicking anything) for ~120 seconds and then I received a 400 with "State token is invalid or expired", which is to be expected

If I reduce the time for the requests from 15 to 5 seconds, some sort of flooding protection seems to kick in (I only see a "EOF" without a response after 5-6 API calls).

Is there a way besides timing out to determine that someone clicked "Deny" on OneLogin Protect? This feels like a bug; as soon as someone clicks "Deny", the next API call should indicate that (other IdPs work that way)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with OneLogin Protect. As you have correctly mentioned that the API does nothing after we click on Deny.

To resolve this what I did was, adding some wait say 30 seconds and if even after that it is 401 in the response then I would cancel the request and redirect user to same page he came from.

You can also ask this to OneLogin support [here](https://onelogin.service-now.com/support). They are very good and response quickly.

Let me know if it helps.